# Why do I get error to make a fragment list in android studio?

Tags: java, android, arrays, android-fragments

I want to make a array list of fragment class Where I have created FragmentOne,FragmentTwo and FragmentThree fragment class so I have wrote

```
Fragment entry1 = new FragmentOne();
Fragment entry2 = new FragmentTwo();
Fragment entry3 = new FragmentThree();
ArrayList<Fragment> FragmentArray = new ArrayList<Fragment>();
ArrayList.add(entry1);
```

But I am getting an error in **add** portion showing `<identifier> expected`.
What is the wrong in this code?

Answer (score -1):

There is an error in the following line:

```
ArrayList.add(entry1);
```

Maybe you mean:

```
FragmentArray.add(entry1);
```